# get data of first two index from json response

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, indexof, swifty-json

Hello i am new to swift and i am calling API through `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJON` and i am able to retrive  response successfully but from that data i want to retrive only first two index of data let me explain you in brief

**Here is my response**

```
{
  "previous_inspection_list" : [
    {
      "inspection_number" : "3",
      "date_inspected" : "2019-04-13",
      "fk_properties_id" : "2",
      "created_by" : "3",
      "signature" : "img_ZbsOx3fx1r1555154350.png",
      "status" : "1",
      "fk_user_id" : "3",
      "signature_name" : "Vishal Parmar",
      "created_date" : "2019-04-13 05:19:10",
      "updated_by" : "0",
      "inspections_id" : "8",
      "updated_date" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "inspection_number" : "2",
      "date_inspected" : "2019-04-13",
      "fk_properties_id" : "2",
      "created_by" : "3",
      "signature" : "img_uVQw3K4pfY1555140089.png",
      "status" : "1",
      "fk_user_id" : "3",
      "signature_name" : "Vishal Parmar",
      "created_date" : "2019-04-13 01:21:29",
      "updated_by" : "0",
      "inspections_id" : "6",
      "updated_date" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "inspection_number" : "1",
      "date_inspected" : "2019-04-13",
      "fk_properties_id" : "2",
      "created_by" : "2",
      "signature" : "img_g6GrjsofPE1555137646.png",
      "status" : "1",
      "fk_user_id" : "2",
      "signature_name" : "Mihir Panchasara",
      "created_date" : "2019-04-13 00:40:46",
      "updated_by" : "0",
      "inspections_id" : "3",
      "updated_date" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "success" : "1",
  "message" : "Successfully."
}
```

as you can able to see my response now i want to retrive only first two index value like below

**Expected OutPut**

**for 1st index expected output**

```
{
          "inspection_number" : "3",
          "date_inspected" : "2019-04-13",
          "fk_properties_id" : "2",
          "created_by" : "3",
          "signature" : "img_ZbsOx3fx1r1555154350.png",
          "status" : "1",
          "fk_user_id" : "3",
          "signature_name" : "Vishal Parmar",
          "created_date" : "2019-04-13 05:19:10",
          "updated_by" : "0",
          "inspections_id" : "8",
          "updated_date" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
```

**2nd Index Expected Output**

```
{
      "inspection_number" : "2",
      "date_inspected" : "2019-04-13",
      "fk_properties_id" : "2",
      "created_by" : "3",
      "signature" : "img_uVQw3K4pfY1555140089.png",
      "status" : "1",
      "fk_user_id" : "3",
      "signature_name" : "Vishal Parmar",
      "created_date" : "2019-04-13 01:21:29",
      "updated_by" : "0",
      "inspections_id" : "6",
      "updated_date" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
```

let me show you my code which i have tried

```
          let sampleArray = data.array
            let firstdict = sampleArray![0]
            print(firstdict)
            let signature_name = firstdict["signature_name"].stringValue
            let inspection_number = firstdict["inspection_number"].stringValue
            let date_inspected = firstdict["date_inspected"].stringValue
            let inspections_id = firstdict["inspections_id"].stringValue
            self.lblFirstInspName.text = signature_name
            self.lblInspNumber.text = "#\(inspection_number)"
            self.lblFirstInspDate.text = date_inspected
            self.inspID1 = inspections_id

            let secondDict = sampleArray![1]
            let signature_name1 = secondDict["signature_name"].stringValue
            let inspection_number1 = secondDict["inspection_number"].stringValue
            let date_inspected1 = secondDict["date_inspected"].stringValue
            let inspections_id2 = secondDict["inspections_id"].stringValue
            self.lblSeconfInspName.text = signature_name1
            self.lblSecondInspNumber.text = "#\(inspection_number1)"
            self.lblSecondInspDate.text = date_inspected1
            self.inspID2 = inspections_id2
```

please see my code i am getting output as expected but when in response there is only one data then i am getting crash on second index because there is no data at second index 
please someone help me

Comment: I would use `Codable` protocol to decode your JSON. Also, do you want to keep all your keys as Strings or do you want them to be proper Ints, Dates, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a safe check before fetching the second one

```
if let sampleArray = sampleArray, sampleArray.count > 1 {
    let secondDict = sampleArray[1]
    let signature_name1 = secondDict["signature_name"].stringValue
    let inspection_number1 = secondDict["inspection_number"].stringValue
    let date_inspected1 = secondDict["date_inspected"].stringValue
    let inspections_id2 = secondDict["inspections_id"].stringValue
    self.lblSeconfInspName.text = signature_name1
    self.lblSecondInspNumber.text = "#\(inspection_number1)"
    self.lblSecondInspDate.text = date_inspected1
    self.inspID2 = inspections_id2
}
```

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: This should work. The key here is to check whether the second index exists at all? If it does, then proceed to extracting it. To be on the safer side, i'd suggest you to apply the same logic for 1st index as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function. I tried to put the important points inside the code.

```
func analysis() {
        let rawData = data as! [String: Any] // Specify value type -> By doing this, you specify the type of value that is "JSON"

        let arrayPreviousInspectionList = rawData["previous_inspection_list"] as! [[String: String]] // Getting "previous_inspection_list" and specifying its type -> it's list of [String: String]

        if(arrayPreviousInspectionList.count >= 2) { // You must check the number of objects in the list
            // first index
            let firstInspection = arrayPreviousInspectionList[0]
            let signature_name = firstInspection["signature_name"]!
            let inspection_number = firstInspection["inspection_number"]!
            let date_inspected = firstInspection["date_inspected"]!
            let inspections_id = firstInspection["inspections_id"]!
            self.lblFirstInspName.text = signature_name
            self.lblInspNumber.text = "#\(inspection_number)"
            self.lblFirstInspDate.text = date_inspected
            self.inspID1 = inspections_id


            // second index
            let secondInspection = arrayPreviousInspectionList[1]
            let signature_name1 = secondInspection["signature_name"]!
            let inspection_number1 = secondInspection["inspection_number"]!
            let date_inspected1 = secondInspection["date_inspected"]!
            let inspections_id2 = secondInspection["inspections_id"]!
            self.lblSeconfInspName.text = signature_name1
            self.lblSecondInspNumber.text = "#\(inspection_number1)"
            self.lblSecondInspDate.text = date_inspected1
            self.inspID2 = inspections_id2

        } else {
            print("--- The number of inspections is less than 2")
        }
    }
```

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English.